# How to have a regex with \| in a mapping

Tags: vim

I have a tabularize command like this `:Tabularize /^[^:]*\()\s\?\|@\)\@<!\zs:\ze.*[^:]/l1` which work for my need,

but I need to enter it as a mapping.
However `:noremap <Leader>a: :Tabularize /^[^:]*\()\s\?\|@\)\@<!\zs:\ze.*[^:]/l1<CR>` fails.

I think it is because of `\|`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [Vim StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Did you try `\\|`?

Answer (score 1):

Romain, as always, had the answer.
It was simply a matter of doubling the backquote, as in `\\|`.